# 3d cut pyramid letter

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

my problem is: how to create a 3d cut pyramid letter.

So, let's consider a single letter "A",
what I want is the possibility to have a 3d "A"
in which one of the two face is smaller than the other.

I thought it was easy: select a face and shrink it,
but then the other face goes crazy.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and show an illustration of your desired goal?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

- Make your letter(s), then extrude them with the text controls.
- When it's about where you want it to be, do Object > Convert to > Mesh.
- Now you can use a boolean modifier to cut it to the final shape.
- Here's some information on the Boolean Modifier, if you need it: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html